# In react-native when using a Flatlist grid, is it possible to have children with higher zIndex?

Tags: react-native, z-index, flatlist

**Context:**

- I have an app (TinyUX) where people can draw wireframes. It uses a Flatlist grid, where each cell can have a background color, and an icon or text.
- The text can be larger than the cell (50x50).
- Assuming left text-alignment I created it so the zIndex went down with each cell (data.length - i)

**Now I'm trying to add right-alignment.**

[image]

So for some cells the text needs to overlap the cells to the right, sometimes to the left. But the background of the cell of either left or right (depending how I set the zIndex in relation to `i` will have the background overdraw the text.

It would seem logical to just make all texts have an zIndex that is higher than the rest of the cell, so they are all above the rest of the cell (icon(s), background colors). But I can't get that to work.

De cell component is nested something like this:

TouchableOpacity (has background color)

- Image (positioned absolute, top left to parent)
- Image (positioned absolute, top left to parent)
- Text (positions absolute, top let to parent.

They have position absolute, so they can overlap.

With my current solution I can make either right or left alignment work.

**Main question:** How can a child of the renderItem component of a Flatlist grid, have a higher zIndex than every other cell in the grid.

**Confusingly..** I just had it working when Metro was not connected, then restarted with Metro and failed again. The component uses React.memo(.. so now I'm not sure if I once was in a state with the fix..